# Item assignment for Dask arrays

Tags: python, vectorization, variable-assignment, dask, python-xarray

I have a piece of code in a model that transforms arrays based on the value of another array one day prior. If the maximum temperature for the current day is lower than the minimum temperature from the day before, the value should be changed to the value of the minimum temperature of the day before the current date. Likewise when the minimum temperature of the before the current day for the current day is higher than the maximum temperature from the day before, the value should be changed to the value of the maximum temperature of the day before the current date. I have two versions that both give the same error, as the Dask arrays do not support item assignment:

```
for ens in range(0,num_ens):
    for lat in range(0, num_lats):
        for lon in range(0, num_lons):
            for day in range(1, 240):
                if max_ens[ens, lat, lon, day] < min_ens[ens, lat, lon, day-1]:
                    max_ens[ens, lat, lon, day] = min_ens[ens, lat, lon, day-1]
                if min_ens[ens, lat, lon, day] > max_ens[ens, lat, lon, day-1]:
                    min_ens[ens, lat, lon, day] = max_ens[ens, lat, lon, day-1]
```

Vectorized version:

```
max_ens[:, :, :, day] = np.maximum(max_ens[:, :, :, day], min_ens[:, :, :, day - 1])
min_ens[:, :, :, day] = np.minimum(min_ens[:, :, :, day], max_ens[:, :, :, day - 1])
```

Does anyone know how to efficiently do this in Dask?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have been trying to implement the where function but the shape of the arrays is adjusted when the where function is applied.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easy to understand why **Dask arrays do not support item assignment?**.  This is because the data are still stored on your hard disk rather than in memory.  So it is not possible to assign or change the values unless you want to overwrite the file on your disk.

Possible solutions are:

1. Execute `load()` or `compute()` so that the data are loaded into memory.  In case that your data are larger than your memory, you have to load parts of them to fit in your memory (e.g., buffering one `ens` per load).
2. Allocate new `var` to store the results and stack them onto a new `ndarray`.  Then write the new `ndarray` out to a new file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Now that dask arrays support [assignment](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-assignment.html) (from version `2021.04.1`), how about:

```
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

# Set up some sample data
min_ens = da.from_array(np.random.random(120).reshape(2, 3, 4, 5))
max_ens = da.from_array(np.random.random(120).reshape(2, 3, 4, 5))

# Define the operations (assuming that the "day" dimension is the last one)
max_ens[..., 1:] = da.ufunc.maximum(max_ens[..., 1:], min_ens[..., :-1])
min_ens[..., 1:] = da.ufunc.minimum(min_ens[..., 1:], max_ens[..., :-1])

# Compute the result efficiently
x, y  = da.compute(min_ens, max_ens)
```